# Using alp - active learning python framework

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am working on a machine learning research project which uses active learning. I am trying to use [alp](https://github.com/davefernig/alp), which provides an implementation of mainstream active learning techniques.

However, I am somewhat confused by the examples provided. The first example is this:

```
from active_learning.active_learning import ActiveLearner
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, X_unlabeled, y, y_oracle = train_test_split(*make_classification())
clf = LogisticRegression().fit(X, y)

AL = ActiveLearner(strategy='entropy')
AL.rank(clf, X_unlabeled, num_queries=5)
```

And I am unsure what data should be in X, X_unlabeled, y & y_oracle. Should:

- `X`contain all of the unlabelled data or both the labeled and unlabelled data.
- 'y' be an empty list or contain the labels for the training data.
- `y_oracle` only contain the labels for the training data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> help(make_classification)

make_classification(n_samples=100, n_features=20, n_informative=2, n_redundant=2,
                    n_repeated=0, n_classes=2, n_clusters_per_class=2, weights=None, 
                    flip_y=0.01, class_sep=1.0, hypercube=True, shift=0.0, scale=1.0, 
                    shuffle=True, random_state=None)

    Generate a random n-class classification problem.

    This initially creates clusters of points normally distributed (std=1)
    about vertices of a `2 * class_sep`-sided hypercube, and assigns an equal
    number of clusters to each class. It introduces interdependence between
    these features and adds various types of further noise to the data.
```

Bold emphasis mine. The function basically generates dummy data for you to play with. Furthermore, as per `help`, the return values are:

```
Returns
-------
X : array of shape [n_samples, n_features]
    The generated samples.

y : array of shape [n_samples]
    The integer labels for class membership of each sample.
```

The samples and labels, which are then passed to `train_test_split` which then shuffles and returns train and test data.